# Android: To use OAuth2 for auth in Google Accounts without Google APIs

Tags: android, google-api, oauth-2.0

In order to use Google APIs before is neccesary to authenticate in a Google account obtaining a auth token with OAuth2.
Well, I would know if it is possible do the opposite: to use OAuth2 in Android for I authenticate in a Google account without use Google APIs.
I only need to auth in the Google accounts in order to execute Google Apps Script scripts, namely, only for make GET or POST parametrized requests to these scripts which will handling this parameters according its code, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible.
Code for do it:

```
public class UploadFileGASActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String GAS_HELLO_WORLD = "url_to_gas_script";
    public static boolean authTokenInvalidated = false;

    public class OnTokenAdquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>{
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future){
            Log.v("CALLBACK","post-getAuthToken");
            try {
                Bundle authTokenBundle = future.getResult();

                if ( authTokenBundle.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN)){
                    String authTokenStr = authTokenBundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                    String accountName = authTokenBundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    String accountType = authTokenBundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
                    Log.v("ACCOUNT NAME",accountName);
                    Log.v("ACCOUNT TYPE",accountType);
                    Log.v("TOKEN",authTokenStr);
                    if (!authTokenInvalidated) {
                        invalidateAuthToken("com.google",authTokenStr);
                        authTokenInvalidated = true;
                        Log.v("CALLBACK","authTokenInvalidated == true");
                        getAuthToken();
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        authTokenInvalidated = false;
                        Log.v("CALLBACK","authTokenInvalidated == false");
                    }
                    HttpUtil httpUtil = new HttpUtil();
                    String responseStr = httpUtil.getResponseFromHttpRequest(GAS_HELLO_WORLD, authTokenStr);
                    Log.v("GAS_HELLO_WORLD",responseStr);
                    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_upload_file_gas);
                    textView.setText(authTokenStr);
                }
                else {
                    Log.v("KEY_AUTHTOKEN","non hai auth token, normal cando non hai conexion");
                }
                if (authTokenBundle.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT)) {
                    Log.e("KEY_INTENT","temos KEY_INTENT");
                    Intent launch = (Intent)authTokenBundle.get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(launch,0);
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (AuthenticatorException e){
                Log.e("OnTokenAdquired.run","AuthenticatorException");
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                Log.e("OnTokenAdquired.run","IOException");
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException e){
                Log.e("OnTokenAdquired.run","OperationCanceledException");
            }
        }
    }
    public void getAuthToken() {
        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        Bundle options = new Bundle();
        OnTokenAdquired onTokenAdquired = new OnTokenAdquired();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        String authTokenType = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
        AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = accountManager.getAuthToken(accounts[1], 
            authTokenType, options, this, onTokenAdquired, handler);
    }
    public void invalidateAuthToken(String accountType, String authToken){
        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        accountManager.invalidateAuthToken(accountType, authToken);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //Activity.RESULT_OK;
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
        Iterator<String> iter = keys.iterator();
        Log.v("KEY_INTENT","requestCode: "+requestCode+", resultCode: "+resultCode);
        Log.v("KEY_INTENT","EXTRAS KEY_INTENT");
        while (iter.hasNext()){
                Log.v("KEY_INTENT",(String)iter.next());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_file_gas);
            Log.v("GAS","UploadFileGASActivity called.");
        getAuthToken();
    }
}
```

And, in HttpUtil:

```
    public String getResponseFromHttpRequest(String httpRequest, String authToken) {
        [..]
        request.setHeader("Authorization", "OAuth "+authToken);
        [..]
    }
```

I hope it helps someone.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is it also possible retrieve the access token expiration time using some Android Google API? Or only through a HTTPS request?